# How to disable webRTC in electron?

Tags: node.js, webrtc, electron, nightmare

i'm writing a bot using nightmare.js with electron.js.
This bot is running in proxy and https://whoer.net shows my original IP because of webRTC.

Is any way to disable that webRTC in electron?

Comment: Are you actually using WebRTC? This would only occur in case of a peer connection

Comment: @KeyneViana i dont use it. but i need to be confident that webRTC wont leak my origin IP

Comment: If you're not using it, it will not leak your IP just because it's enabled.

Comment: @KeyneViana ok, its great. Can I have some profs or smg like that?

Comment: If you understand better how webrtc works you'll be able to see if there's any related traffic sniffing packets. You could search for STUN packets for example to see if a connection is being established. But what that site is telling you is that your browser has webrtc.. as any modern browser

Comment: @KeyneViana ok i just use proxies to access to linkedin so i need to be confident that webRTC is not leaking my original IP to linkedin?
So my question is https://whoer.net leak my origin IP when i'm in proxy and i dont make any peerconnections (i'm use webRTC) i just come to whoer and he can see my origin IP, and i'm worried about that because i can disable webRTC in my bot browser electron.

Comment: Use a browser to access whoer and see if that happens following this instructions https://whoer.net/blog/article/how-to-disable-webrtc-in-various-browsers/

Comment: @KeyneViana already do that - visit whoer throught bot and he says that webRTC is enabled. But the main problem is that i cant find a way to DISABLE webRTC in electron browser.

Comment: The point is, go to whoer with webrtc disabled in your PC browser and see if your ip will show.. if yes, than there's nothing with webrtc